# Rails 2.3 console refuses to come up after switching from rvm to rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I converted this Rails 2.3 application 2 years ago to use `Bundler`, so that is not the issue.

The `script/console` script absolutely refuses to load `<APP ROOT>/config/boot.rb`.

The that file will load is if I am in the `config` directory in an `irb` session, or from  with:

```
require './config/boot'
```

but:

```
require 'config/boot'
```

does not work.

Is there some sort of path screwup in `rbenv` that is causing these problems? What figured to be a 15-minute job last night has had my production system down for 8 hours. It ***must*** be something simple.

- rbenv
- ruby-build
- ruby-2.1.5
- Rails 2.3.8
- Bundler v1.10.6
- RubyGems 2.2.2

Again, note that this application has worked with Bundler for 2 years now. It's just the switch from `rvm` to `rbenv` that has caused this apparently.

I have long ago followed these instructions, and confirmed that they are still valid: http://bundler.io/v1.3/rails23.html

---

*** script/console ***

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require 'commands/console'
```

NOTE: Also noticed that nothing in `vendor/plugins` loads.

***Entire Error***
/home/myapp/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)
    from /home/myapp/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from script/console:2:in `'

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with rbenv, can you post the contents of `script/console`

Comment: Hmm, that should work.  What error do you get?

Comment: cannot load such file - script/../config/boot

Comment: This has got to be some weird Bundler issue.  vendor/plugins aren't loading either.

Comment: bundler 1.10.6? I assume rather than 1.6.  Or did you mean rubygems?  Maybe you've not got completely rid of rvm and rbenv and rvm are conflicting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not work:

```
script/server
```

Does work:

```
./script/server
```

Comment: Maybe explain why one works and the other doesn't. It will help provide a fuller answer